# Mathematica overload memory constructing a matrix

Tags: matrix, memory

I have the following [list](https://pastebin.com/yprG2Bxx) of {x,y} positions and I'm trying to connect the neighbors with a distance 1 a.u in a matrix, with the following

```
MAT = 1.0*(1 - Unitize[DistanceMatrix[POINTS] - 1.0]);
```

And after that I'm aiming to calculate the eigensystem.

But it turns out that mathematica quits the calculation. This means that I'll need to find another way to define this matrix constructed with this rule of distances. Do you have any suggestion to doing that?

Comment: Why do you need the `Eigensystem` of all these points' distance matrix? i.e what are you trying to achieve with this? Have you considered using any of `SingularValueDecomposition` or `PrincipalComponents` or `KarhunenLoeveDecomposition` ?

Comment: For the distance matrix, $41584^2$ entries of Mathematica's standard 64-bit reals is around 12.9 GiB if you want it dense. The sparse matrix of MAT is much smaller obviously since it's full of zeros. I have 256 GB of RAM total and it's currently using 39GB on the `Eigensystem` computation, but it is taking too long to complete. You will need at least that much. If you only request the top k eigenvalues, then it will work quickly but may be inaccurate as it complains about poor convergence of the Arnoldi method.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well, I was trying to calculate at least for the case where the eigenvalue is equal to 0 and also see the eigenfunction for this case as well. I haven't tried what you have suggested yet, but I'll see how to do this. About the memory allocation, how did you calculate this?

Comment: For the memory of the distance matrix, 41584^2 * 8 / 2^30. gets you GiB size of the dense distance matrix, although annoyingly ByteCount[dmtx] comes in almost exactly 10x larger. The rest was just looking at task manager. Using NumericArray[data, "Real32"] might keep the size down - but you can't use this with Eigensystem unfortunately.